# How to get last value of observable by key using debounceTime

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

```
 employeeChanged: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
 setInterval(() => {
     this.employeeChanged.next(1);
     this.employeeChanged.next(1);
     this.employeeChanged.next(2);
     this.employeeChanged.next(2);
     this.employeeChanged.next(3);
     this.employeeChanged.next(3);
 },1000);

 this.employeeChanged.pipe(debounceTime(1000),distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(((key) => {
            console.log(`Employee update: ${key}`);
 }));
```

My example looks like this. I want to get latest value by key that i provide to subject observable so my output looks like this

```
Employee update: 1
Employee update: 2
Employee update: 3
```

Which operator i need to use to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the same value for `debounceTime` and `setInterval` delay, the `debounceTime` time span won't pass and no values will be emitted.

Now, there are two options:

1. Lowering `debounceTime` timer, but it will result in only dispatching the latest value since the debounce will ignore the close-emitted values
2. Removing `debounceTime` operator and get your desired behavior

I assume you wanted some sort of delay between emissions, you can use [`bufferTime`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/buffertime.html) to collect the distincted values for some time span, then use  [`mergeAll`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/mergeall.html) to flatten the collected values

```
employeeChanged
  .pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    bufferTime(1000),
    mergeAll()
  )
  .subscribe(key => {
    console.log(`Employee update: ${key}`);
  });
```

Comment: To be more precisely, my example with interval just simulate scenario, when i get information from socket to update data inside my frontend application. Problem with this is that socket sometimes send data to fast and with the same key, so i need take last value of current key in period time for example 500ms. Your solution not gonna work, because `distinctUntilChanged` prevent next update with the same key. I should write this in my question, but now i think you understand my problem. Thanks anyway :)